# Getting a NaN error when when calling a setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a setTimeout function that calls itself and is broken by a counter. However, I keep gettng a NaN error. Can someone help me?

```
<script language="javascript">
    function Tests() {
        this.i = 0;
    }


    Tests.prototype.increment_test = function () {
        if (this.i > 2) {
            return;
        }
        alert(this.i);
        this.i++;

        setTimeout(this.increment_test, 30);
    }

    ta = new Tests();
    ta.increment_test();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a function from setInterval the context in "this" variable is not your object but "window" object. You need to pass the context in the following way:

```
setTimeout(this.increment_test.apply(this), 30)
```

Comment: I think you mean `this.increment_test.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not permanently bound to the `increment_test` function.

You can reference `this` in a variable, and use it inside an anonymous function.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() { self.increment_test()}, 30);
```

Or you can use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the calling context to a function.

```
setTimeout(this.increment_test.bind(this), 30);
```

Or you can make a little utility that binds the context.

```
function _bindCtx(fn, ctx) {
    return function() { return fn.apply(ctx); };
}
```

and call it like this.

```
setTimeout(_bindCtx(this.increment_test, this), 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

When `setTimeout` calls a function, it changes its context to `window`.  So, inside `increment_test`, `this` isn't what you think it is.

You need to do it like this:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    self.increment_test();
}, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Tests() {
    this.i = 0;
    // Next line added. I think what it's the best solution because it can 
    // increase the speed and reduce the consumption of resources (memory) 
    // when used with setTimeout()
    this.increment_test = this.increment_test.bind(this);
}


Tests.prototype.increment_test = function () {
    if (this.i > 2) {
        return;
    }
    alert(this.i);
    this.i++;

    setTimeout(this.increment_test, 30);
}

ta = new Tests();
ta.increment_test();
```